# Delphi's code formatter uses too many spaces (using menu...)

Tags: delphi, code-formatting, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition. I have used this program for a while now without problems, but now the code formatter (Menu -> Project -> Format Project Sources) formats everything correctly, except it doesn't use the common 2 spaces for indentations, but uses 8 spaces.

I didn't change anything. I was coding and formatting a few times and it worked well, but suddenly, while using the code formatter a few times in a project, it started formatting with 8 spaces before everything.

When I use the <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> keys, it formats normally using 2 spaces only.

Can anyone tell me why Delphi decided to use 8 spaces randomly, and how I can change it back to normal settings?

I tried Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Language -> Formatting -> Delphi -> Indent, and changed "indent at line continuation " to 3, which worked so far, but when I type in 1 or 2, it uses 4 instead of 1 or 2.

Why??

**EDIT:** Of course, reinstalling Delphi (probably also the whole Windows alongside my Delphi installation) would solve the problem, but I would like to avoid this.

Comment: In the meantime I just press Ctrl+D, but I want the menus project formatter to user proper formatting nevertheless

Comment: They both should be the same

Comment: Have any of the settings changed under User Interface|Editor|Source?

Comment: Interface|Editor|Source looks like nothing has changed..

Comment: The menu item and Ctrl+D do the same exact thing. Ctrl+D is just a shortcut key to that menu item. The settings dialog affects both of them exactly the same way, so what you describe isn't possible; there is no behavior difference, because they're both running the exact same code in the exact same way from the exact same menu item.

Answer (score 0):

In the Delphi Formatter settings under Line breaks, if you have "Line breaks before single instructions in control statements" set to "No" or "As is", any if statements with just a single instruction formats with too many spaces. If I set it back to "Yes", the formatting works as expected.

Seems to be a bug in the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Delphi 11.2` and this is still not solved.
I select `Project -> Format Project Source` and on some files it formats indenting with 2 spaces and in others with 8 spaces.
If I press `CTRL+D` then it indents with 2 spaces.

I tryed to set to NO and then to YES de option "`Line breaks before single instruction`" but it didn't work.

I couldn't find any information on this bug.